# parallelize for loop on python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run a python selenium script where there are more than 10,000 rows exists on that page. I am running a for loop as belows:

```
    list = []
    for i in range(10000):
        try:
            xpath  = '//*[@id="home-contents"]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i+3)+']/td[3]'
            xpath_quantity = '//*[@id="home-contents"]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i+3)+']/td[6]'
            quantity = a.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath_quantity).text
            if(int(quantity)>499):
                print(str(i+1) +' is done')
                t_5 = a.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath).text
                list.append({"name":t_5,"quantity":quantity})
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(i) +' found exception')
            break
```

The above code executes successfully, but it's taking more than 20 minutes to complete the process.

Is there any way I can do multiprocessing or multi threading  so that the execution can be made more faster?

Comment: can you share the URL? Also please explain what the code actually does is and share the html code of the page. Do not share the html as code not as image

Comment: Hi, the page can be accessed from private network only, so I cannot share it now. But, the end goal is to parallelize for loop which scraps data.